# Is it possible to define a curve to be "infinitely close" in distance and direction to a line?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, differential-topology

This is a quandary that came to mind while pondering the question [What is the mathematical definition of a "figure six"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2330584/what-is-the-mathematical-definition-of-a-figure-six) .

The following is my effort to formalize the idea of two curves "merging tangentially" and becoming "infinitely close without touching".  In the following, one of those curves is the line $\mathscr{L}$.

Suppose I define a smooth plane curve $\mathscr{C}$ as an open set of points such that the limit of the angle between the tangent to $\mathscr{C}$ and some line $\mathscr{L}$ approaches $0$ as the distance $d[\mathbf{p},\mathscr{L}]:\mathbf{p}\in\mathscr{C}$ between a variable point on the curve and $\mathscr{L}$ approaches $0$.

Assert $\mathscr{C}\cap\mathscr{L}=\emptyset$.

In addition, let there be a line, $\mathscr{L}_{\perp}$ perpendicular to $\mathscr{L}$, and some neighborhood, $\mathscr{A}$ of the point of intersection of $\mathscr{L}$ and $\mathscr{L}_{\perp}$.  Also, one end of $\mathscr{C}$ shall lie outside of $\mathscr{A}$.

Within $\mathscr{A}$, require for some arbitrarily small, fixed $\varepsilon>0$, that

$$0<d[\mathbf{p},\mathscr{L}_\perp]<d[\mathbf{p},\mathscr{L}]<d[\mathbf{p},\mathscr{L}_{\perp}](1+\varepsilon):\mathbf{p}\in\mathscr{A}\cap\mathscr{C}.$$

Does this consistently describe a smooth, open curve with a boundary point at the intersection of $\mathscr{L}$ and $\mathscr{L}_\perp$, but which does not include that boundary point?

Now, if $\mathscr{L}$ is replaced by a colinear segment which also intersects $\mathscr{L}_\perp$ and smoothly continues the erstwhile end of the curve $\mathscr{C}$ at some point outside of $\mathscr{A}$, is the end of $\mathscr{C}$ within $\mathscr{A}$ now closed?  In other words, now that the point $\mathscr{L}\cap\mathscr{L}_\perp\in\mathscr{C}$.

Comment: I hesitate to post an answer when the question looks as if it could bear a closer scrutiny than what I'm going to give it right now. One way of looking at what it means to say that a certain line $\mathscr L$ in a plane is tangent to a certain curve $\mathscr C$ in the plane at a point $P$ on the curve $\mathscr C$ is as follows: Every line through $P$ whose direction is close to that of $\mathscr L$ but rotated counterclockwise from the direction of $\mathscr L$ crosses $\mathscr C$ at $P$ in one direction, and every such line rotated clockwise from $\mathscr L$ crosses in $\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$the other direction.